# WordPress Plugin rewrite rules stop working occasionally

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

We have problem with rewrite rules in plugin stop working occasionally. When visiting url, we get 404. Frequency is very seldom, 1-2 months or more. Perhaps after web host server restart.

I am under impression that:
Most people seem to say put `add_rewrite_rule()` in `add_action( 'init', '...' )` hook.

You should absolutely not put flush_rules() in init but in plugin activation (according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules )

Hence - confusion.

Current code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'xxx_activation');

function xxx_activation() {
    xxx_addrewriterules();
    //other stuff
}

function xxx_addrewriterules() {

    //add rewrite rules
    add_rewrite_rule(
        xxx_DOCUMENT_VIRTUALDIRECTORY . '/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.;=]+)/?$',
        'index.php?document=$matches[1]',
        'top' );

    //flush rules
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

I have a hunch to trial/error moving rewrites to 'init' and flush to 'activation' - but it is hard to confirm since we would need at least 3+ months before suspecting changes are working, so would prefer actual confirmation or best practice example.

Thanks!